# Azure Batch won't auto-scale down

Tags: azure-batch

I've created a pool and a job tied to a pool in Azure Batch.  After I add a task to the job, I can see that the active tasks from this auto-scale formula returns an array of '1's after a few minutes:

$tasks = $ActiveTasks.GetSample(TimeInterval_Minute * 5);
//returns [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

However, after I terminate & delete the task and wait 30 minutes, Azure still thinks that I have an active task, as the formula evaluates to the same array of '1's.  Is there something wrong with this formula?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting either of `$TargetDedicatedNodes` or `$TargetLowPriorityNodes`. Simply creating a `$tasks` array doesn't result in actionable resize targets for Batch to process.

Also, you should verify that you have no active tasks through the jobs->task list view.